# BASH shell use regex to get value from file into a parameter

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I've got a file that I need to get a piece of text from using regex. We'll call the file `x.txt`. What I would like to do is open `x.txt`, extract the regex match from the file and set that into a parameter. Can anyone give me some pointers on this?

#### EDIT

So in `x.txt` I have the following line

```
$variable = '1.2.3';
```

I need to extract the `1.2.3` from the file into my bash script to then use for a zip file

Comment: `var=$(grep regex file)` or you're going to have to be a lot more specific.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. First glance, that looks like it may be what I need. I'm actually wanting to extract a group number from the grep (group 1). Can that handle this?

Comment: You mean like `group [0-9]\+`? Sure. Or if you just want the number, `grep -oP '(?<=group )[0-9]+'`

Comment: No, he probably means `var=$(sed -ne 's/^[^=]*= *'\([^']*\)'.*/\1/p' file)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I've updated my question above to clarify what is in the file and what I need to get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the grep-chop-chop technique

```
var="$(grep -F -m 1 '$variable =' file)"; var="${var#*\'}"; var="${var%\'*}"
```

Comment: Explanation please.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) to do it efficiently<sup>†</sup> in a single pass:

```
var=$(sed -ne "s/\\\$variable *= *['\"]\([^'\"]*\)['\"] *;.*/\1/p" file)
```

The above works whether your value is enclosed in single *or* double quotes.

Also see [Can GNU Grep output a selected group?](https://superuser.com/questions/11130/can-gnu-grep-output-a-selected-group).

```
$ cat dummy.txt
$bla = '1234';
$variable = '1.2.3';
blabla
$variable="hello!"; #comment

$ sed -ne "s/\\\$variable *= *['\"]\([^'\"]*\)['\"] *;.*/\1/p" dummy.txt
1.2.3
hello!

$ var=$(sed -ne "s/^\\\$variable *= *'\([^']*\)' *;.*/\1/p" dummy.txt)

$ echo $var
1.2.3 hello!
```

<sup>† or at least as efficiently as `sed` can churn through data when compared to `grep` on your platform of choice. :)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into `sed` as it seems to be a great tool. Unfortunately the above didn't seem to work for whatever reason for me

Comment: I see; your input is actually a PHP script, so the line is probably indented; I removed the `^` from the regular expression, go ahead and try again.

Comment: And there, since it's a PHP script you're dealing with, I updated the regexp to also deal with double-quotes. :)

Comment: Thanks for updating. The code does work however I've already used the code above now which is working. I've upvoted your answer. Thank you again

Comment: No problem.  I assume the assignment you were interested in is always essentially at the top of the file and cannot preceded by any tests of the form `$variable ==...` (the `grep` in the accepted answer would match those instead.) :)  Also make sure that you modified the acepted answer to check for double-quoted strings as well as different spacing around `=` if you think your php source had either, or else you'd be missing values. :)

Comment: Thanks for the follow up comment. The code I'm matching is always just one unique line with `$variable = '1.2.3';` however it is indented. It is never in double quotes and never repeats in the file. I can guarantee this as I am the only one with access to edit said file. The point of this code was to generate two separate zip files but needed the version number of the code inside the php script to generate the full file path

Comment: Can you break down how this works? I'm trying to adapt, and I'm not understanding parts of the regex, and mainly this bit of the sed command: `;.*/\1/p` does it just mean print the first patch?

Answer (score 1):

If all the file lines have that format (`$<something> = '<value>'`), the you can use `cut` like this:

```
value=$(cut -d"'" -f2 file)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't as it's a php script