# Obtaining value out of a script with bash

Tags: bash

I have a file with many lines, with lines such as so:

```
PHP_VERSION="5.3.12"
NPM_VERSION="1.10"
```

From a linux command line, how would I take out just the version number? For this example, how would I get an output like `5.3.12` if for say I wanted the PHP version out of the given input file.

Comment: I modified my question to be less opinion based. I clearly don't know how to do it and need guidance.

Comment: You can easily cobble something together with `sed(1)`... you'd need to do `sed -ne "s;${PKG}_VERSION=;;p" YourFileHere`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like:

```
var="$(grep -F -m 1 '$variable =' file)"; var="${var#*\'}"; var="${var%\'*}"
```

Reference: [BASH shell use regex to get value from file into a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337550/bash-shell-use-regex-to-get-value-from-file-into-a-parameter)

Comment: Thanks, the reference you gave me helped me a bunch. I was able to create the command which parsed out the version number.

`sed -ne "s/PHP_VERSION= *['\"]\([^'\"]*\)['\"].*/\1/p"`

Answer (score 3):

Your trying to get it with `bash`?

```
. /path/to/file
echo $PHP_VERSION
```

?

Comment: Rather than source the entire file, I'd evaluate just the line matching `PHP_VERSION` with `eval "$(grep PHP_VERSION /path/to/file)"`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have power to evaluate that script.

Comment: Pardon?  Would you mind explaining this in more detail?